# Laravel Verify Email Address showing 403 error page

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-codes

Verify Email Address is showing error `403 Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page`. The error occurs when user click on the verify email address button in the email.I tried breaking at line Auth\VerificationController@verify but controller does go to this method. What I am doing wrong here.

On the localhost it is working fine. I am having this issue in the hosting server

**Routes Setting**

```
 Auth::routes(['verify' =>  true]);
```

**Mail Server settings**

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=587
 MAIL_USERNAME=yourgmailid@gmail.com
 MAIL_PASSWORD=gmailpassword
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I have gone through the stackoverflow Questions none  fit or exactly solves this issue

**Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails**

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->route('id') == $request->user()->getKey() &&
        $request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

Comment: Publish some code.

Comment: Is that enough information

Comment: please put your controller code

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem because I needed `URL::forceScheme('https');` in AppServiceProvider to make Laravel Telescope to work behind the proxy. I haven't yet found a solution make both Email Verify and Telescope to work in my environment but removing `URL::forceScheme('https');` fixed the `403`.

Some developers have reported that adding `protected $proxies = '*';` to TrustProxies 
 middleware has helped to 403 problem, didn't work for me but maybe worth trying. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: This worked for me, thanks